# Pandas: ValueError: Shape of passed values is (110, 10), indices imply (111, 10)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I hope someone can help me with this error.

I'm collecting the price of a cryptocurrency every millisecond using a websocket. The information it brings me is like this:

> Recent Trades: [{'timestamp': '2021-02-20T01:15:37.264Z', 'symbol': 'XBTUSD', 'side': 'Sell', 'size': 637, 'price': 56302.5, 'tickDirection': 'ZeroMinusTick', 'trdMatchID': 'b89d919f-01c9-e510-a141-f01785bff8da', 'grossValue': 1131312, 'homeNotional': 0.01131312, 'foreignNotional': 637}, {'timestamp': '2021-02-20T01:15:38.256Z', 'symbol': 'XBTUSD', 'side': 'Sell', 'size': 592, 'price': 56302.5, 'tickDirection': 'ZeroMinusTick', 'trdMatchID': '2b213054-d62a-55a7-fcef-5aa183f24e2c', 'grossValue': 1051392, 'homeNotional': 0.01051392, 'foreignNotional': 592},
> {'timestamp': '2021-02-20T01:15:38.521Z', 'symbol': 'XBTUSD', 'side': 'Buy', 'size': 8070, 'price': 56303, 'tickDirection': 'PlusTick', 'trdMatchID': '63fdc9ac-1c86-8507-58d6-054755304bf5', 'grossValue': 14332320, 'homeNotional': 0.1433232, 'foreignNotional': 8070}, {'timestamp': '2021-02-20T01:15:38.521Z', 'symbol': 'XBTUSD', 'side': 'Buy',
> 'size': 29832, 'price': 56303, 'tickDirection': 'ZeroPlusTick', 'trdMatchID': '6f93d2f3-f679-80ab-5e89-0ae1dfc2d84d', 'grossValue': 52981632, 'homeNotional': 0.52981632, 'foreignNotional': 29832}, {'timestamp': '2021-02-20T01:15:38.521Z', 'symbol': 'XBTUSD', 'side': 'Buy', 'size': 1023, 'price': 56303, 'tickDirection': 'ZeroPlusTick', 'trdMatchID': '6a058aec-a6e2-83d0-5c39-29bb00537049', 'grossValue': 1816848, 'homeNotional':
> 0.01816848, 'foreignNotional': 1023}, {'timestamp': '2021-02-20T01:15:38.521Z', 'symbol': 'XBTUSD', 'side': 'Buy', 'size': 1172, 'price': 56303, 'tickDirection': 'ZeroPlusTick', 'trdMatchID': 'c1ff8488-1bc9-9167-ae80-7b579c01df4b', 'grossValue': 2081472, 'homeNotional': 0.02081472, 'foreignNotional': 1172}, {'timestamp': '2021-02-20T01:15:38.521Z', 'symbol': 'XBTUSD', 'side': 'Buy', 'size': 9903, 'price': 56303, 'tickDirection': 'ZeroPlusTick', 'trdMatchID': '184cd0bf-f157-1cd7-3676-af6607cd1f07', 'grossValue': 17587728, 'homeNotional': 0.17587728, 'foreignNotional': 9903}]

It is a variable length data set. It can bring 20, 130, 150, 84, but not more than 200.
What I do with that data is to convert it into a dataframe to extract only the last data of the set and insert it into a csv.
It actually works fine, but after some time, maybe 10 min. I get this error. I was trying with some solutions to this kind of problems, but the truth is that I couldn't solve it.

This error had not appeared before, I was even testing the code in a test environment and everything went quite well. First I started to get an error concerning the key to extract the last element of the data. I changed it to the one below, but now I get this error.

The error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\tania\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\si
> mgr = BlockManager(blocks, axes)
> File "C:\Users\tania\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\si
> self._verify_integrity()
> File "C:\Users\tania\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\si
> construction_error(tot_items, block.shape[1:], self.axes)
> File "C:\Users\tania\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\si
> raise ValueError(f"Shape of passed values is {passed}, indices i
> ValueError: Shape of passed values is (110, 10), indices imply (111,
> return create_block_manager_from_arrays(arrays, arr_names, axes)
> File "C:\Users\tania\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py", line 1675, in create_block_manager_from_arrays
> construction_error(len(arrays), arrays[0].shape, axes, e)
> File "C:\Users\tania\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py", line 1694, in construction_error
> raise ValueError(f"Shape of passed values is {passed}, indices imply {implied}")
> ValueError: Shape of passed values is (110, 10), indices imply (111, 10)

or this error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "c:/Users/tania/OneDrive/Escritorio/bot/bitmex_ws/main-pandas.py", line 57, in <module.py", line 57, in run()
> File "c:/Users/tania/OneDrive/Escritorio/bot/bitmex_ws/main-pandas.py", line 26, in run    .py", line 26, in run
> df = pd.DataFrame(ws.recent_trades())                           te-packages\pandas\core\f
> File "C:\Users\tania\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 486, in **init**            )
> mgr = arrays_to_mgr(arrays, columns, index, columns, dtype=dtypete-packages\pandas\core\i)
> File "C:\Users\tania\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py", line 74, in arrate-packages\pandas\core\iys_to_mgr                                                           ays
> return create_block_manager_from_arrays(arrays, arr_names, axes)                                                                    te-packages\pandas\core\i
> File "C:\Users\tania\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py", line 1675, in createmply {implied}")       _block_manager_from_arrays                                           10)
> construction_error(len(arrays), arrays[0].shape, axes, e)
> File "C:\Users\tania\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py", line 1694, in construction_error
> raise ValueError(f"Shape of passed values is {passed}, indices imply {implied}")
> ValueError: Shape of passed values is (108, 10), indices imply (109, 10)

This is the part of my code:

```
while(ws.ws.sock.connected):  
     df = pd.DataFrame(ws.recent_trades())
     co = len(df)-1
     data = [df['timestamp'][co],                
             df['side'][co],                
             df['price'][co]]
     print(data)
     with open('C:/Users/tania/OneDrive/Escritorio/bot/csv/BTCUSD_pandas.csv', 'a', newline='') as file:
          writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=',')
          writer.writerows([data])
     sleep(0)
```

This is the output:

> print(data)

> ['2021-02-20T01:30:43.124Z', 'Sell', 56246.0]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you are using pandas for some other reason, you might be better off and more efficient to just use python.

You can get the last element of the list assuming ws.recent_trades() comes through as a list. It doesn't matter the size of the list.

```
data = ws.recent_trades()[-1] 
print(data['timestamp'], data['side'], data['price'])
```

then write to the csv file

PS. I don't know the actual answer to your df question, but I assume somewhere in the data, you are getting a dictionary that is missing data and it's throwing things off. You can write in some error checking but that's a bit of overhead that you may not want.